# iterating a php object

Tags: php, iteration

I am sure this is a complete noob question but I am trying to iterate through an api response from stripe.com and I am able to echo out the array  in php to be something like this:

```
{ "count": 3, 
"data": [ { "amount": 29900, 
        "object": "plan", 
        "interval": "month", 
        "livemode": false, 
        "currency": "usd", 
        "name": "vb Group unlimited", 
        "id": "vb-std-group2" }, 
      { "amount": 9900, 
        "object": "plan", 
        "interval": "year", 
        "livemode": false, 
        "currency": "usd", 
        "name": "vb Group to 20", 
        "id": "vb-std-group" }, 
      { "amount": 1900, 
        "object": "plan", 
        "interval": "year", 
        "livemode": false, 
        "currency": "usd", 
        "name": "vb-Individual", 
        "id": "vb-std-individual" } 
    ] 
}
```

What I'm trying to do is echo out the "data" array info. Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string you have is JSON encoded. Decode it using `json_decode` into a PHP object, say `$obj`. Then, `$obj['data']` is an array. Iterate over it using a foreach loop.

```
foreach($obj['data'] as $key=>$object)
    foreach($object as $key=>$value)
        echo $key . " : " . $value;
```

Comment: Thanks @xbonez.  I was missing the json_decode.  That got it.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$reponseData = $response['data'];
foreach($reponseData as $eachDataObj)
{
    foreach($eachDataObj as $key => $val)
    {
        echo $key . " => ".$val;
    }
}
```

This assumes that $response is already an object, if it is actually just TEXT then you have to use

```
$response = json_decode($response);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Check this out it would help you**

```
$myjson = '{ "count": 3, 
"data": [ { "amount": 29900, 
        "object": "plan", 
        "interval": "month", 
        "livemode": false, 
        "currency": "usd", 
        "name": "vb Group unlimited", 
        "id": "vb-std-group2" }, 
      { "amount": 9900, 
        "object": "plan", 
        "interval": "year", 
        "livemode": false, 
        "currency": "usd", 
        "name": "vb Group to 20", 
        "id": "vb-std-group" }, 
      { "amount": 1900, 
        "object": "plan", 
        "interval": "year", 
        "livemode": false, 
        "currency": "usd", 
        "name": "vb-Individual", 
        "id": "vb-std-individual" } 
    ] 
}';

$data =json_decode($myjson);
$arrData = get_object_vars($data);
foreach($arrData as $key=>$value){


    $arrData[$key] = $value;
}

//print_r($arrData['data']);
foreach($arrData['data'] as $ke=>$va):
     foreach($va as $k=>$v):
         echo $k."-".$v."<br/>";
     endforeach;
endforeach;
```